# pyqt thread qRegisterMetaType warning/crash

Tags: multithreading, pyqt

I'm writing a pyqt program utilising the Qwizard. From one screen I am running a thread and starting a command line program via Popen. However I'm getting the following warning message:

QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
(Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

The program usually continues but crashes sporadically immediately after this point, leading me to feel that it is related.

As the code of the program is too much to attach, here are the relevant snippets:

```
class Fee(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, options=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        #set the given options
        if options:
            self.__options = options

    def copy(self, devicename, outputfilename): 
        self.__device = devicename
        self.__outputfile = outputfilename
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        cmd = self.__getCommandLine(self.options, self.__device, self.__outputfile)
        logging.info("Running Fee with command %s" % (cmd))
        #start the process
        output = ""
        process = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout= PIPE, stderr= STDOUT)
        stderr = process.communicate()[1] 

class FeeManager(QtCore.QObject):
    def copyAndVerify(self):
        self.__fee = Fee(self, self.options)
        self.connect(self.__fee, QtCore.SIGNAL("finished()"), self._setCopyFinished)
        self.connect(self.__fee, QtCore.SIGNAL("progressUpdated(QString, int, QString)"), self._setCopyProgress)

        devicename = self.device.blockdevice
        self.__image_outputfilename = "output_file.img")
        self.__fee.copy(devicename, self.__image_outputfilename) 



class FeeWizardPage(QtGui.QWizardPage):
    def initializePage(self):
        #already earlier in another wizard page is the following: self.feemanager = FeeManager(self, info) 
        self.connect(self.wizard().feemanager, QtCore.SIGNAL("copyProgressUpdated(QString, int, QString)"), self.updateCopyProgress)
        self.connect(self.wizard().feemanager, QtCore.SIGNAL("verifyProgressUpdated(QString, int, QString)"), self.updateVerifyProgress)
        self.connect(self.wizard().feemanager, QtCore.SIGNAL("finished(PyQt_PyObject)"), self.setDone)
        self.wizard().feemanager.copyAndVerify()
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid this message and hopefully bring some stability to the program. I've searched the internet and this forum, and while I've tried a number of suggestions for others, none have worked for this problem. Even when I comment out all signals and connects, I still get the same warning message.

Can someone help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas? Anyone at all?